# How to do repeated-measure ANOVA with binary data on R

Tags: r, binary, anova

I am looking at survival in Ascidian larvae over a period of three weeks and if settler size, or the petri dish they are in (since each petri dish has a random number of ascidians within it) or the run they belong to have any significant impact on their survival. I am not expecting any significance for petri dish and run, however my professors still wants me to include them in my ANOVA to be able to statistically exclude them later.
Here is all the coding that I have been trying to run:

```
 Ascidians <- Ascidians %>%
      gather(key = "Week", value = "Survival", Survival.W1, 
         Survival.W2, Survival.W3) %>%
  convert_as_factor(Week)

Ascidians %>%
  group_by(Settler.Size, Week) %>%
  shapiro_test(Survival)

ggqqplot(Ascidians, "Survival", ggtheme = theme_bw())+
  facet_grid(Week~Settler.Size, labeller= "label_both")

res.aov <- anova_test(data = Ascidians, dv = Survival,
                      wid = Run, within = c(Settler.Size, Week))

get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

However when I run the shapiro_test i get this error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x sample size must be between 3 and 5000
i Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
i Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
```

And it will not allow me to run the,

```
res.aov <- anova_test(data = Ascidians, dv = Survival,
                  wid = Run, within = c(Settler.Size, Week))
```

I tried doing it as a one-way to start off and then keep adding variable until I have added all the variables, however, it won't let me run the two-way repeated ANOVA much less the three-way repeated ANOVA
I think this is due to the data being binary?
Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!!

My data

```
    Run Petri.dish Settler.Size Survival.W1 Survival.W2 Survival.W3
1   1          1     20130.03           0           0           0
2   1          1     23694.39           1           1           1
3   1          2     19421.20           1           1           1
4   1          2     25820.88           0           0           0
5   1          2     21432.59           0           0           0
6   1          2     18605.33           0           0           0
```

Comment: Please include all the non-base R packages that you are using. From which package is the function `ggqqplot` ?

Comment: These are all the packages that I used
    library(tidyverse)
    library(ggpubr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(rstatix)
    library(reshape2)

Comment: I am not sure if ANOVA is the appropriate method you use here. If I can understand the hypothesis in my opinion  a time-to-event analysis is more appropirate?!

Comment: Hi @TarJae, I've never heard of a time-to-event analysis, would it allow me to check for significance in three dependent variables at the same time? (settler size, week and survival). Thank you!

Comment: Hi. If you want to investigate the impact of (settler size or week or any other variable) on the survival of your specimens thenyou should perform a survival analysis (=time to event analysis). You measure the survival of your specimens at 3 specific time points this my qualify your data for a repeated-measure anova. But you state: "I am looking at survival in Ascidian larvae over a period of three weeks and....". In this case for me it is a survival analysis. But just perform both and compare the results. Other question: Is this your complete data or just the first 6 specimens?

Comment: Okay makes sense, I will try the survival analysis then and compare, thank you!
It is just the first 6 specimens, there are 198 rows in total :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to group by with `Week` only and not `Settler.Size` since grouping by `Settler.Size` will give you only one row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

Ascidians %>% group_by(Week) %>% shapiro_test(Survival)
```

Comment: Thank you! That does allow me to run the shapiro_test. However, it still won't let me run the two-way repeated measure ANOVA...any clue on how to fix that? Thank you again!

Comment: @MarineBioStudent It works if you do `anova_test(data = Ascidians, dv = Survival,wid = Run, within = Week)`

Comment: I tried running it but when I run it I get this error (I think because of the binary data in survival): 
    `Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
    Keys are shared for 591 rows`